# 数値項目用のINPUT TYPE=TEXTの枠、フォーカスがあたったら、カーソルを一番右に配置したい

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

皆様　いつもお世話になっております。

標題の件、数値項目が入る枠は、事前に値が入っていて内容の変更・もしくは削除する場合は、バックスペースキーで操作を行いたいものではないでしょうか？デリートキーではなく。

## ====質問====

INPUT TYPE=TEXTの枠にフォーカスがあたったら、カーソルを一番右に配置する方法があれば教えてください。ちなみに現況当該枠は以下コーディングを果たしてあります。

```
// 数量枠は．．．数値のみ入力可・フォーカス外れたらカンマ表示・フォーカスしたらカンマ外した表示
    $("input[name=amount]").on({
        "keydown": function(e) {
            var k = e.keyCode;
            if (!((k >= 48 && k <= 57) || (k >= 96 && k <= 105) || k == 32 || k == 8 || k == 9 || k == 46 || k == 39 || k == 37)) {
                return false;
            }
        },
            "blur": function() {
            var num = $(this).val();
            num = num.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+$)/g, "$1,");
            $(this).val(num);
            },
            "focus": function() {
            var num = $(this).val();
            num = num.replace(/,/g, "");
            $(this).val(num);
        }
    });
```

追記：　とても大事なことを伝え忘れていました。CSSで当該枠を右詰め表示をしています。

```
/* 数量入力列のみ右つめ表示 */
input[name='amount'] {
    text-align: right;
}
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のような感じでしょうか。

```
"focus": function(e) {
  var num = $(this).val();
  num = num.replace(/,/g, "");
  $(this).val(num);
  if (this.selectionStart != null) {
    this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
  } else {
    this.createTextRange().select();
  }
}
```

Comment: urin様　ありがとうございました。期待通りの動作が達成できました。皆さん同じ悩みを持たないのものなのですかねぇ

Answer (score 0):

javascriptで、空のvalueへ文字列をセットするとカーソルが文字列終わり（右端）に来るので。
以下の様に、試しに書いて見ました。（クリック位置で、選択されたりするのはご愛嬌で,スクリプトを組まなくても、マウスで入力エリア右端をクリックすれば良い様な気もします。）

```js
$(function(){
        $("input").focus(function(){
            if($(this).attr('type') === 'text'){
                var data = $(this).val();
//                $(this)val("").val(data);
                $(this).val("");
                $(this).val(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
    input {
        text-align: right;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="test data in!!">
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="test data2 in!!">
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="test data3 in!!">
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="test data4 in!!">
```

Comment: yyz様　いつも大変お世話になっております。大事なことを伝え忘れていました。本文に追記致しました、ご確認頂ければ幸いです

Comment: スニペットにcss  ”text-align: right;”を追加しました。

Comment: ご用意頂きましたテキストボックスへ順次に1,2,3,4と入力して、シフト＋タブで遡って、各テキストボックスへ「1」を入れていくと14,13,12,11となってしまいます...。
数値専用の枠として、これが41,31,21,11となったら、嬉しいのですが、欲張りすぎですかね。